# certificate and provisioning profile error

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile

I have lost my old computer.so I revoked and download a new certificate(delevopment and distribution).

Then deleted all the old provisioning profile and create the new one,But when I take all this to my project .my xcode has a error message about **"No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"**.

**Certificates has private key in my keychain and provisioning profile is vaild**  in organizer.I have do nothing about the old APPID and device.

What's the problem? any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: [Have You Google Something before questioning.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57059/how-do-i-transfer-my-ios-developer-profile-to-another-computer)

Comment: Did you download the certificate from apple for WWDC certificate?

Comment: the APPLEWWDRCA.cer? i have already downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the certificate from developer.apple.com Go to Member center and then Certificate and download the certificate associated with your provisioning profile and double click on it to add it into the keychain. Then it should work.

Comment: "download the certificate associated with your provisioning profile"is that means download the certificate and provisioning profile? or download the certificate and then use oraganizer to download provisioning prifile? and other else?

Answer (score 0):

1.get the private key form your old computer and download the certificate ,provisioning profiles .but this not fit for you.
2.create a new certificate with a CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest file in you computer .you can try this.

Comment: i have created a new one. and the certificate have private key.i have also created a new provisioning profile.but the error still there.